# Kernel panic appears without any reason

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash, kernel-panic

I need your help. My MacBook Pro 13" from 2017 sometimes just shuts down without any reason and the error code after the next boot is a kernel panic. I can't find the exactly same error code online, I hope you can help me. Here it is:

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801446520a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80147d4f3b, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff80587a7854, CR3: 0x00000000288e3000, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0
RAX: 0x00000000000000b5, RBX: 0xffffff91593233c8, RCX: 0xffffff80387a76a8, RDX: 0xffffff91593233c8
RSP: 0xffffff9159322f30, RBP: 0xffffff9159323040, RSI: 0x0000000000000000, RDI: 0xffffff8046a3f6a0
R8:  0xffffff9159323348, R9:  0xffffff9159323518, R10: 0xffffff9159323448, R11: 0xffffff9159323018
R12: 0xffffff9159323588, R13: 0xffffff9159323518, R14: 0xffffff80387a76a8, R15: 0x0000000000000000
RFL: 0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0xffffff80147d4f3b, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff80587a7854, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 0, VF: 1

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff9159322990 : 0xffffff801433bb1b 
0xffffff91593229e0 : 0xffffff80144733e5 
0xffffff9159322a20 : 0xffffff8014464e5e 
0xffffff9159322a70 : 0xffffff80142e2a40 
0xffffff9159322a90 : 0xffffff801433b207 
0xffffff9159322b90 : 0xffffff801433b5eb 
0xffffff9159322be0 : 0xffffff8014ad24f9 
0xffffff9159322c50 : 0xffffff801446520a 
0xffffff9159322dd0 : 0xffffff8014464f08 
0xffffff9159322e20 : 0xffffff80142e2a40 
0xffffff9159322e40 : 0xffffff80147d4f3b 
0xffffff9159323040 : 0xffffff80147cd795 
0xffffff91593234f0 : 0xffffff801475a65c 
0xffffff9159323620 : 0xffffff8014759861 
0xffffff9159323800 : 0xffffff8014751ea0 
0xffffff9159323b30 : 0xffffff8014746b19 
0xffffff9159323b50 : 0xffffff80147ca983 
0xffffff9159323cf0 : 0xffffff80147c971d 
0xffffff9159323d30 : 0xffffff801464fff5 
0xffffff9159323d60 : 0xffffff8014616a90 
0xffffff9159323d90 : 0xffffff8014608bda 
0xffffff9159323dc0 : 0xffffff801460889b 
0xffffff9159323f50 : 0xffffff80146092a7 
0xffffff9159323fa0 : 0xffffff80142e213e 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
19C57

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.2.0: Sat Nov  9 03:47:04 PST 2019; root:xnu-6153.61.1~20/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: C3E7E405-C692-356B-88D3-C30041FD1E72
Kernel slide:     0x0000000014000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8014200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8014100000
System model name: MacBookPro14,1 (Mac-B4831CEBD52A0C4C)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 29750869013061
last loaded kext at 29137966603624: >!AXsanScheme   3 (addr 0xffffff7f97e3e000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 29244988714160: >!AXsanScheme 3 (addr 0xffffff7f97e3e000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@fileutil   20.036.15
>AGPM   111.4.1
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!AHDA  283.15
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 4.5.21
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   4.5.21
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.2f4
>pmtelemetry    1
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.3
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!IKBLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.3
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!ABacklight    180.1
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.3
>eficheck   1
>!AMCCSControl  1.13
>!ACameraInterface  7.6.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.61.1
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.0.9
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3420.1
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
@kext.triggers  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>!AGraphicsControl  4.5.21
|IOAVB!F    800.17
>!ASSE  1.0
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.2f4
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.2f4
@!AGPUWrangler  4.5.21
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    4.5.21
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.2.8
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  569.3
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   569.3
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    800.14
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHub  1.2
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.6
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AActuatorDriver   3420.2
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHS!BDriver   3420.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.2f4
|IO!B!F 7.0.2f4
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.2f4
>!AMultitouchDriver 3420.2
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3420.4
>!AHSSPIHIDDriver   58
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.4
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.2
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!AHSSPISupport 58
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.1
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.4.7
>!A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.60.3
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.0.2
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.40.7
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.0.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOTimeSync!F   800.14
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

I really hope there is someone who can help me!

Comment: there are reports which have "AXsanScheme" in last loaded/ unloaded kext, but they also have some other "kernel extension in backtrace". Have you edited the report ?

Comment: @ankii No, I did not edit it

Comment: Bad RAM, bloated battery... - check the RAM and the battery...

Comment: @klanomath thanks for these tips, but unfortunately neither the RAM nor the battery showed some issues according to the tools rember and coconut battery. The official Apple Hardware Test also told me everything's ok

Comment: Searching for the error code I found several pages mentioning kernel panics for no apparent reasons and they were related with bloated batteries leading to defective mainboards (and CPUs). I don't think that secondary damage can be detected by Coconut Battery.

Comment: @klanomath Do you have an advice what I can do now?

Comment: Personally I would unscrew the rear casing and check the battery packs. Else: Apple Authorized Service Provider/Genius Bar...